# What does 'his bowels had turned to water' and ' He was a veteran of a hundred rangings by now' mean?

Tags: grammar

> Will shared his unease. He had been four years on the Wall. The first time he had been sent beyond, all the old stories had come rushing back, and **his bowels had turned to water**. He had laughed about it afterward. **He was a veteran of a hundred rangings** by now, and the endless dark wilderness that the southron called the haunted forest had no more terrors for him.

What do the two bolded passages mean? Bowels should contain food, why it would turn to water? About ' a veteran of a hundred ranging', I consider it as 'a veteran of a hundred skills'. Ranging=skills. Is that right?

Comment: What do you think they mean?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: If you keep reading the book, you will find out what "ranging" is.  (I assume you cal look up the meanings of "veteran" and "hundred" ... these are standard words in English.) This often happens in literature: you read something, and it only makes sense later, after you read more.

Comment: "Veteran of a hundred rangings" -> he is probably a **Ranger**, so it appears to mean 100 missions on the wall over those 4 years. When your "bowels turn to water", it means that your bowels don't do their work of extracting the water from the food, thus resulting in **diarrhea**. It is often due to extreme stress.

Comment: This quote is from the novel A Game Of Thrones by George R R Martin, in case anyone's wondering.

Comment: @MorganFR The only hole I'd pick in that is that the passage talks about being 'on the wall' and then being 'sent beyond', so my take would be that 'rangings' are expeditions 'ranging *beyond* the wall'.

Comment: While it can be understood form context, 'ranging' isn't generally a noun (speaking only from British English), it is the sort of construction and word play that one gets quite a lot in Fantasy novels, especially those with a lot of 'world building'. It's intended to give the language some roots, or 'local colour' arising from in the world described. IMO, obviously

Comment: Hello Arctic, why do you think your question received two downvotes and one close-vote? As @Mitch commented, you need to show us what you understand (preferably using dictionary definitions) and tell us what you don't understand. That's the way you should ask a question here.

Comment: “No two persons ever read the same book.”

― Edmund Wilson

Answer (score 3):

This is an old trope meaning to be seized with fear. The earliest that the Ngram viewer finds is from the periodical [*Punch*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bowels%20turn%20to%20water%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1936&lr=lang_en#q=%22bowels%20turn%20to%20water%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1936,lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&start=10) from 1843. The phrasing's use is more directly illustrated in Rudyard Kiplings's story ["Gemini"](https://books.google.com/books?id=43n6QkFbL48C&pg=PA426&dq=%22bowels%20turned%20to%20water%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFodWKlofOAhWFSiYKHctjDA0Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22bowels%20turned%20to%20water%22&f=false) from *Indian Tales* (1890):

> Then a new fear came upon me and my **bowels turned to water**

Consider a terror so great that the person so afflicted feels that he will lose control of the workings of his intestines.

*To range* can mean to wander extensively, so a *ranging* is the action of such travel, here apparently through a haunted forest.

Comment: 'old trope'? Intestinal problems yes, but 'turning to water' is more extreme than I've ever heard before. But if Kipling used it, then I guess it's established.

Comment: @Mitch The earliest I can find it 1843. It's not *Beowulf*, but it's older than I am, so I count that as old.

Comment: Great. Another driveby downvoter. Is the answer wrong? incomplete? infelicitous? Readers are left wondering by this discourtesy.

Comment: (Not my downvote.) The help center discourages answers to questions which should be closed. This question, which is out of scope (interpretation request and lacking results of research), might attract downvotes on answers.

Comment: @MετάEd Of course, and if you (or anyone else) had downvoted the answer and given that reason, I would have had neither a problem nor reason to comment. No one would have been led to wonder if the answer was factually incorrect. In fact, such a comment would have served one of this site's purposes, namely to inform the the questioner of his intellectual and ethical failings. As it is, no one really knows (although your conjecture is is a reasonable one), which is why driveby downvoters are a curse upon this site.